# FileSystemWatcher not detecting changes properly

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, filesystemwatcher

I was trying to make an application which can popup a notify message whenever a new row is added to the database.i was using mysql and changed the default engine to csv engine so that i can use the FileSystemWatcher to detect any changes.The filesystemwatcher is triggering whenever a row is deleted but the problem is its not triggering changed event when a new row is added to the database.I also observed that when a row is deleted the "Date Modified" is changing but when I add a new row its not updating. Please help me.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher();
    fsw.Path = "C:\\xampp\\mysql\\data\\doubts\\";
    fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    fsw.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(func);
}

private void func(Object obj,FileSystemEventArgs e) 
{
    notifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Application;
    notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = 
        "Addition of new row to the database detected...";
    notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(4000);
}
```

Comment: Can you verify that the file on disk actually has changed? Maybe MySQL hasn't flushed the changes yet.

Comment: You're trying to detect changes within a database by monitoring file system events. This is really not a good approach and I think the trouble you're running into underscores that.

Comment: Actually when i use FLUSH TABLES in the database,everything is working fine...can u tell me y the data hasnt flushed the changes for addition of new rows while its flushing for deletion ...

Comment: Also is there any method to trigger event without using csv engine whenever a new row is added.please note that ultimately i need to connect this with a .net application....

Comment: I believe that is what the `SqlDependency` class is for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx. But I think it only works with MSSQL.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you poll the database periodically to check for changed records.

If your query is expensive, you could create an `AFTER INSERT` or `AFTER UPDATE` trigger which inserts into another table, then poll that table.

If this still is not sufficient, you can do this: From your application, run a command like

```
SELECT "WaitForChanges", SLEEP(999);
```

Create a trigger which kills this select via the [KILL QUERY command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/kill.html): [How to do this from a stored procedure](http://mysqlpreacher.com/wordpress/2009/07/mysql-processlist-showkill-processes/).